# How to formulate a query and view for the following structure?

Tags: mysql, query, view

Consider the following table structure:

```
TableA
ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC
Ro1      A         1
Ro1      A         1
Ro7      A         3
Ro2      C         1
Ro3      B         1
Ro3      B         1
Ro6      B         2
Ro4      C         2
Ro5      A         2
```

> Task: Create the table stipulated above with two columns (ColumnA, ColumnB), then develop a query/view that will produce the structure as shown in view above, of which ColumnC is found within a view and not within the table and its contents are automatically generated by considering changes of values in ColumnA and ColumnB respectively.

I simply don't understand how to formulate this query.

Comment: This is impractical in SQL.  Use your application language for programming it.

Comment: Can you explain the logic of how ColumnC is calculated? It might be just me, but I fail to see any.

Comment: The value of column c is determined with columnA and ColumnB a mysql case statement would produce the view necessary